# Bottle - Handing hashtags in request

Tags: python, bottle

I have a route that looks like this,

```
@app.route('/search/<query>')
def search(query):
    # query DB, return a template, etc.
```

which fetches some records containing `%query%` from the DB. However, it breaks when that query contains one or more `#`.

From what I've read, this is an issue with URL encoding (`#` is not converted to `%23` or something along those lines).

How can I fix this? Tried setting `response.charset = 'US-ASCII` in `search(query)` as per another answer's recommendations, but no luck.

Comment: "Breaks" how?  Also worth mentioning that the URL fragment (everything after an unescaped `#`) is not even sent to your webserver.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be an issue with your front-end code failing to properly encode the url.

I just ran a quick test and bottle correctly resolved `/search/number%20%236` to `/search/number #6`.

It's likely that whatever your front-end is using to encode your urls is interpreting the hash sign as a fragment identifier and failing to encode it correctly. You may want to either use another library to encode the urls before passing them on or encode it manually.